# Angular - On resize change html element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 5. What I am trying to do is a responsive side navigation bar. When the window width changes I need some events to apply (css, content etc). In my example I want to change the inner Html - text, when the window width is below of 1080 pixels.

I tried three ways. By javascript and ng-model but nothing.

Html:

```
<div id="nav-left">
    <mat-list>
     <mat-list-item><a id="elp1" [routerLink]="['/']" fragment="intro-text" ng-model="innerHtml"> Welcome </a></mat-list-item>
     <mat-list-item><a id="elp2" [routerLink]="['/']" fragment="introduction"> Introduction </a></mat-list-item>
     ...
    </mat-list>
</div>
```

Component (first way):

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event?) {      
      this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
      let bgScreen = true;
      let smScreen = true;
      if(this.screenWidth < 1080 && smScreen){
        document.getElementById("elp1").innerHTML = "New";

        smScreen = false; 
        bgScreen = true;

      }else if(this.screenWidth >= 1080 && bgScreen){
        document.getElementById("elp1").innerHTML = " Welcome ";

        bgScreen = false;
        smScreen = true;        
      }else{
        console.log('problem');
      }
    }
```

In this case I get a console error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Component (second way):

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
        onResize(event?) {      
          this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;

          if(this.screenWidth < 1080){
            let element = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("elp1");
            element.value = "New";

          }else if(this.screenWidth >= 1080){
            let element = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("elp1");
            element.value = "Welcome";      
          }else{
            console.log('problem');
          }
        }
```

With the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
```

Component (third way & ng-model):

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
            onResize(event?) {      
              this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;

              if(this.screenWidth < 1080){
                let innerHtml :string = "New";

              }else if(this.screenWidth >= 1080){
                let innerHtml :string = "Welcome";      
              }else{
                console.log('problem');
              }
            }
```

With no errors but it doesn't work.

1) The first problem are the above errors.
2) and secondly as you see in the "first way" example I tried to add flags trigger effects and realized that didn't worked either. Variables "bgScreen" and "smScreen" are always true. I put those for a better coding flow.

I don't want to use jQuery. Only typescript or with angular (ng-model) way. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `ElementRef` and then `ElementRef.nativeElement` to access the dom element.

Comment: Give me an example. Write a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using data binding to set the content of the link:

```
<div id="nav-left">
  <mat-list>
    <mat-list-item><a [routerLink]="['/']" fragment="intro-text"> {{introText}} </a></mat-list-item>
     ...
  </mat-list>
</div>
```

The public property `introText` can be modified when the window is resized:

```
introText = "Welcome";

@HostListener("window:resize", ["$event"])
onResize(event) {      
  this.introText = window.innerWidth < 1080 ? "New" : "Welcome";
}
```

or, as an alternative, you could define `introText` as a getter (not handling the `resize` event):

```
get introText(): string {
  return window.innerWidth < 1080 ? "New" : "Welcome";
}
```

Comment: Which is the best option the first or the second for performance?

Comment: For performance, I would prefer the first one. The call to `window.innerWidth` probably takes more time than simply accessing the `introText` variable.

Comment: By the way, I saw your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50189242/1009922): you don't need to set `[innerHTML]` if you use interpolation. Choose one or the other, not both. After checking again: use `[innerHTML]` because interpolation does not accept HTML markup (unless you sanitize it).

Answer (score 0):

To get element instead of using `document.getElementById("elp1")` try `ViewChild` of angular if child element of component, or `ElementRef` for component itself. As here it looks child element of Component you could use `ViewChild`

You will get the access to element in angular component.

so now your HTML would be

```
<mat-list-item><a #elp1 [routerLink]="['/']" fragment="intro-text"> Welcome </a></mat-list-item>
```

and in @component

```
import { ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
.
.
@ViewChild('elp1') link;

//And assign values like below now.
this.link.nativeElement.innerHTML = "New";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: Where did you define this `@ViewChild('elp1') link;` in component ?
Any fiddle to have a look ?

Comment: Yes inside component. When I put outside under import it shows me other error: ReferenceError: link is not defined. Ok wait for a fiddle.

Comment: yes, it should be inside the component. After the Html change and this change, Link must hold the link cmp. Any fiddle please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/weblaravel/b4ef53jb/   I guess that should work but is not all...