# Adding Font Awesome 5 icon from Angular 5 component

Tags: angular, font-awesome, angular-fontawesome

I am using Font Awesome 5 (angular2-fontawesome - package) with Angular 5.

What I am trying to do is to import fa icon from component.

Html:

```
<mat-list>
     <mat-list-item><a [routerLink]="['/']" fragment="intro-text" [innerHTML]="introText"> {{introText}} </a></mat-list-item>
     ...
</mat-list>
```

Component:

```
introText = "Welcome";

@HostListener("window:resize", ["$event"])
onResize(event) {      
  this.introText = window.innerWidth < 1080 ? '<i fa class="fas fa-home"></i> <h1>1</h1>' : "Welcome";
}
```

When I am above from 1080 pixels it shows me "Welcome" and when is below it shows me the number 1 bold and big.

The problem is that icon it didn't show up. I checked to put...

```
<i fa class="fas fa-home">
```

in Html and it works but from component it didn't. Why and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: If you use `[innerHTML]`, you can remove `{{introText}}`.

Comment: I have the same issue. It's even in the DOM, but it's like zero px in size, so nothing is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 has removed Font Awesome import , you need to explicitly import Font Awesome  .

Comment: I don't understand. Try to read my question again. I have already import font awesome with npm the package "angular2-fontawesome".